# post array of objects into sails controller

Tags: node.js, sails.js

What does the controller need to look like to create a record for each object in the passed array? Do I create a for loop?

Here's what I have:

```
Agent.findOneById(req.query[0].agentId, function(err, agent) {
  console.log(agent);
  for (i = 0; i < req.query.length; i++) {
    Record.findOrCreate({userDN: req.query[i].userDN}, {
        name: req.query[i].name,
        owner: agent.id
    }).exec(function (err, newRecord) {
        if (err) return res.negotiate(err)
        res.json(newRecord);
    })
}
```

This create one object, there are 15 items in the array.

Here's one object from the array per the request:

```
query:
{ '0':
   { userDN: '99999',
     name: 'Test User',
     agentId: '4' },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the built-in [Bluebird library](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird). Specifically, [Promise.all()](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#all---promise).

Code example (also using lodash `forEach` to simplify things):

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');

...

Agent.findOneById(req.query[0].agentId, function(err, agent) {
  console.log(agent);
  var promises = [];
  _.forEach(req.query, function(record) {
    promises.push(Record.findOrCreate({userDN: record.userDN}, {
      name: record.name,
      owner: agent.id
    }));
  });
  Promise.all(promises)
    .then(function(records) {
      res.json(records);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      return res.negotiate(err);
    })
}
```

Comment: I am having an issue where the client receives `{ [Error: read ECONNRESET] code: 'ECONNRESET', errno: 'ECONNRESET', syscall: 'read' }` if I send more than 20 users at once. Do you have any idea why this would be happening or how to resolve?